# TYPO3 - Extbase SEO Urls

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x, realurl

I developed an extension which heavily uses a REST Data Source and i have no local tables in typo3 DB. No it is known that the urls are not really human readable.

So what i want now to do is this:

In my rootline i have a page which includes my plugin and i want to have a url structure like this:

```
www.example.com/category-title-1/seo-friendly-poduct-name.html
```

Some explanation to the different url parts:

```
[category-title-1] => This is a dynamic part from the Webservice and i don't know them in advance
[seo-friendly-poduct-name] => This comes from the Webservice to.
[.html] => filename ending
```

I've read a lot of RealUrl and saw something about lookup tables and so on.
But as i have noch local lookup tables i can't use that.

Is the wished url structure generally achievable?

Can somebody try to explain what would be the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not only use your own lookup tables but also user defined functions:

```
...
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    // your extension parameter identifier
    'yourParamIdentifier' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar'   => 'tx_yourextension_plugin[parameter]',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:yourextension/pi1/class.tx_yourextension_realurl.php:&tx_yourextension_realurl->handleRealURLCoding',
        )
    ),
    // set the page id with your plugin to paramater identifier to hide the page segment from url
    123 => 'yourParamIdentifier', 
),
...
```

In the method handleRealURLCoding you can handle your own realurl rules without having any table.

Comment: ok.  thanks for that. How would look the url then? www.example.com/yourParameterIdentifier and what if i want to  have this part [yourParameterIdentifier] dynamic "yourParamIdentifier" is that possible to ? Maybe with some wildcards ?

Comment: The last two lines in the array hides this path segment so you can choose your own path segment for your controller and actions.

Comment: I think you will have to live with something like `www.example.com/products/category-title-1/seo-friendly-product-name`, (`products` being `yourParamIdentifier`) - that's correct, @sreuter, no?

Comment: No, you can omit this parameter from path with `123 => 'yourParamIdentifier'`. That means that on page 123 this parameter is set implicit in background.